# What does "new construction only" mean for Recessed Light Housing?

Tags: basement-refinishing, recessed-lighting

My basement ceiling is not yet covered with drywall.   Does this mean I can use recessed light housing for new construction or does that require access from the top as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless there are other restrictions such as clearance to framing members or insulation or open space above them you can use them.  "New construction" is when the framing is open and not covered by drywall<sup>*</sup>; the fixture is typically attached to a framing member.  As opposed to "old work" which is where it's closed on both sides and you're going through a small hole in the drywall; the fixture is often attached by clamps to the drywall itself.

<sup>*</sup> With some "new construction" fixtures you need to have the wall open on the side you're working; with others you can get away with having just the other side open because the fixture will give you enough room to work in.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this.  Everyone I talked to at the store told me I can't but looking at the thing I couldn't imagine why not.

Comment: @PeterQ: I saw and answered this question before I saw your ["extreme clearance requirements"](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6964/22) question.  You may not be able to use those lights in this case; I'd wait and see what answers you get there.

Comment: I don't understand: I may not be able to install which lights?  BTW, I just talked with my electrician and he confirmed what you said: no problem installing the "new construction" housing from underneath.  So if I decide to not use the IKEA ones I might go with these.

Comment: @PeterQ: I meant the IKEA lights.  Are you also considering some other type -- neither question mentions that.

Comment: Yes, good point.  I'm open to any good solution.  Just posted another question: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/recommendations-for-recessed-lights-for-a-basement